# error --- Error c2872 : ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++

I have creating a new project and I am adding existing project reference and calling one class from the existing one. I am getting the below error --- Error c2872 : ambiguous symbol

Comment: You should provide further details if you want someone to be able to help you.

Comment: The compiler also tells you which symbol is ambiguous and what alternatives it has found.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the compiler sees two identical symbols, e.g., you write your own `cout` in namespace `yours`, then use `using namespace yours;` and `using namespace std;`, and then use `cout` (without the namespace). The compiler is unable to identify which `cout` you actually meant. So in this situation you could use `yours::cout`.